# C - (ptr = = &ptr) What is *ptr?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This might be a stupid question, but I have a little problem with understanding of C Pointers. Even more when it comes to arrays. For example:

```
char ptr[100];
ptr[0]=10;

fprintf(stderr, "&ptr: %p \n ptr: %p \n*ptr: %d\n", &ptr, ptr, *ptr);

if ( &ptr == ptr ) {
  fprintf(stderr, "Why?\n");
}
```

How is this even possible? 'ptr' is at the adress &ptr. And the content of ptr is the same as &ptr. Then why is *ptr = 10 ???

Comment: Most importantly, `ptr` is a __misnomer__, since it isn't a pointer, but an array.

Comment: @sbi The name `ptr` is both though in this case depending on the context. In `&ptr == ptr` , ptr is an array in the left operand, (and the result of & gives you a pointer to an array. The right operand is a pointer, it's the same as &ptr[0] . Ptr in itself is an array, not a pointer though-

Comment: @nos: No, it isn't both. It decays to a pointer when used in that expression, but it isn't a pointer.

Comment: @nos: That's like saying 5 is both a double and an integer because you can do `double x = 5;`. `ptr` is an exclusively an array, and only by *conversion* can it be anything else.

Comment: `if (&ptr == ptr)` is not valid C. `char (*)[100]` does not implicitly convert to `char *` or vice versa. In an ideal world your compiler would reject the code, but it's probably at least giving a warning. The whole point of this being, `&ptr` and `ptr` differ in *type* not numeric value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The address of the first element of the array is the same as the address of the array itself.

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or address-of `&` operators, or is a string literal being used to initialize another array in a declaration, an expression of type "N-element array of T" will be implicitly converted ("decay") to type "pointer to T" and the value will be the address of the first element in the array.

If the expression `a` is of type "N-element array of T", then the expression `&a` is type "pointer to N-element array of T", or `T (*)[N]`.

Given the declaration

```
T a[N];
```

then the following are all true:

```
Expression         Type        Decays to
----------         ----        ---------
         a         T [N]       T *
        &a         T (*)[N]    n/a
        *a         T           n/a
```

The expressions `a` and `&a` both evaluate to the same *value* (the location of the first element in the array), but have different types (pointer to T and pointer to array of T, respectively).

Comment: I am quite sure you mean Nth-element, but I am not 100% sure, could you clarify?
(more in the text than the table below it)

Answer (score 3):

`ptr` (which, as sbi says, is really an array) decays to `&(ptr[0])` (`char *` to first element)

This is the same address as `&ptr` (a `char (*) []`), even though they are different types.

Comment: But it's not the same type though. ptr is a char*, &ptr is a char(*)[100]

Comment: @nos: The *object* `ptr` is a 100-element array of `char`.  The type of the *expression* `ptr` is `char [100]`, which is implicitly converted to type `char *` when it appears in the `printf` call.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int arr[5];
    arr[0]= 7;

    fprintf(stdout,"%p %p %d",&arr[0],arr,*arr);

    if( (int)&arr == (int)arr ) printf("good\n");
    else printf("bad\n");
    return 0;
```

}

This will work....